# Space or new line is showing in restapi response in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, rest

I am getting issue in Rest API response. In pretty section it is looking good when seeing in raw section some space is showing.

[image]

Comment: Where is your code?  What investigation have you done?

Comment: Thanks for your response. there was one helper class, because of that class this issue was coming. Now it has fixed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to search your string for all newline characters (in php storm you can also use system.lineseparator I believe), and then replace them with empty values. So let's take a function for this. You could go with str_replace(), however in this example we'll use preg_replace().

So:

```
    <?php
    $string = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $string);  // \r and \n 
     //being the newline characters and $string the searchstring.
    ?>
```